# Relation between AuthService and UserService

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have an AuthGuard that implements a canActivate Method where I check, through the AuthService, if there's a jwt saved on local storage.

My first question is: is enough? Or I have to check with my backend also if the token is valid?

SecondQuestion: If the token is valid, I want to retrive the user's info. Maybe I saved it on local storage the first time the user logged but if it there isn't I have to ask it to the backend.

My problem is handle the multiple requests by components of getUser().
This method checks if user is defined or undefined, if undefined checks if there's info in localstorage and if there isn't info does an http.get() to get the info from the backend.

In my opinion if I put this in the AuthGuard, getUser() can return directly the object user without do multiple http.get() because I know before load the page that the user is yet loaded.

Which's the best approach?

Comment: Never rely on your client side for security.  However, you can assume the token is valid, and make a request with it.  Then using an interceptor capture a 401 response and redirect your site to a login page.

Comment: Thank you @cgatian. What about the userService. Which is the best approach to avoid multiple http.get() when the user is undefined?

Comment: I believe we did something in the interceptor where you basically set a Boolean and pause all http requests if it's toggled. I'd had have to look at the code to see though